# Obtener id de un componente de ElemenUi VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, elementui

Necesito obtener un id de el componente de ElementUi `<el-table-column>` para poder eliminar los resultados que llegan de mi base de datos MySQL.

Esta es mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi componente de elementUi

```
el-table
    :data="tableData.filter(data => !search || data.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))"
    max-height="500">
    <el-table-column
      prop="id"
      label="Id"
      width="150">
</el-table-column>
  <el-table-column
      prop="username"
      label="Username"
      width="120">
    </el-table-column> 
.....
```

Estos son las acciones de editar y eliminar

```
 <el-table-column
      align="right"
      fixed="right"
      width="150px">
      <template slot="header" slot-scope="scope">
        <el-input
          v-model="search"
          size="mini"
          placeholder="Username"/>
      </template>
      <template slot-scope="scope">
       <button class="buttons-edit edit" @click.prevent="deleteUser(tableData[scope.$index].id)">editar</button>
         <button class="buttons-edit delete" @click.prevent="deleteUser(tableData[scope.$index].putLink)">Eliminar</button>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
```

Para poder traer el id de la columna Estoy usando :

> tableData[scope.$index].id

pero no he logrado satisfactoriamente.

Este es mi method para eliminar el usuario la cual recibe un id que no he podido obtenerlo

```
deleteUser(id) {
      if (window.confirm("Desea eliminar el usuario " + this.id+ "?") == true) {
        console.log("Eliminado");
        this.$http.post("user/delete/" + id).then(res => {
          if (res.status == 200) {
            alert("Se ha eliminado el usuario!");
            this.getUsers();
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert("Cancelado", "", "error", {
          buttons: false,
          timer: 600
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Me funciono usando la funcion scope.row.id

```
   <button class="buttons-edit delete" @click.prevent="deleteUser(scope.row.id)" authKey="default">Eliminar</button>
```